# How do create a button that when pressed enters a calendar view, allowing the user to select a date?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-studio-2.0

How do code a button that when pressed enters a calendar view, allowing the user to select a date? (In both the Main Activity and xml)

Comment: have you coded anything yet? maybe if you paste your code we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add library when you can do it yourself..... I used an editText here, you can do anything, an image, a button, textview

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //To show current date in the datepicker
                Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                        Log.e("Date Selected", "Month: " + selectedMonth + " Day: " + selectedDay + " Year: " + selectedYear);
                        editText.setText(selectedMonth + "/" + selectedDay + "/" + selectedYear);
                    }
                },year, month, day);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vzw.www.myapplication.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```